# Rate of convergence vs number of iteration

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, rate-of-convergence

Can anyone explain to me the difference between [rate of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence) and number of iterations for a numerical algorithm? Is it correct to say rate of convergence measure how fast the sequence approach a limit and that the higher rate of convergence means the better?

Answer (score 1):

The **number of iterations** measures how long you choose to run the algorithm.

The **rate of convergence** measures how accurate your answer will be depending on how long you choose to run the algorithm.